# I can't explain why the adverb 'so' is wrong in this context

Tags: grammar, adverbs, syntax

"Hi, I hope you are doing well in this so strange situation."

As an adverb of degree, it should work, but I have never heard this and it sounds wrong. Is there a reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [nice article](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/so) from the Cambridge Dictionary which explains the reason.

In short, you don't use "so" before an adjective and a noun, as is your case with "strange situation". There are a few different ways to paraphrase this sentence to make it work:

> I hope you are doing well in this **very** strange situation.
>
> I hope you are doing well in **such a** strange situation.
>   *("this" is implied and therefore it needs to be omitted)*
>
> I hope you are doing well in **so strange a situation**. *(here, we're using the construction "so ADJ a/an NOUN", which is uncommon nowadays in everyday speech)*